# how to output a list of bool for a 2 dimensional list, true if the elements are same?

Tags: python, list

please see my code,

```
#the 2 dimensional list is indefinite,,  my_2d_list[index1][index2], where both index1 and index2 is indefinite,
my_2d_list = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['a','d','c'],
    ['a','d','c','s','t'],
    ['a','d','c','s','t']
]

bool_list = []

def bool_func(my_2d_list):
    #what should I place here?
    pass

print(bool_list)
```

output should be [True,False,True,False,False] , bool_list[0] is true since all are letter a, bool_list[1] is false since b is different from d, if one of them is different it is false, bool_list[3] and bool_list[4] are false since you cannot compare them with the first 2 list whose length is only 2.

please help with the function bool_func content, thanks.

Comment: have you looked into zip?

Comment: Will your list always be to parallel lists? i.e. will `my_2d_list` always have two list elements of identical size?

Comment: adjusted my answer according to the updated version, please check below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the question was updated with a more complex 2d list I updated my answer as below. First, I convert the 2d list into a data frame and then use pandas tools on it to return the desired output.

```
newdata = pd.DataFrame(my_2d_list).fillna('NA')
display(newdata)
bool_list =[]

for i in range(len(newdata.columns)):
    bool_list.append(newdata[i].nunique()==1)
    
print(bool_list)
```

Also, I did not use the function because I don't see a need. However, if you really want to keep the function you can do:

```
bool_list =[]

def bool_func(my_2d_list):
    newdata = pd.DataFrame(my_2d_list).fillna('NA')
    for i in range(len(newdata.columns)):
        bool_list.append(newdata[i].nunique()==1)
    pass

#need to call function before printing bool_list:
bool_func(my_2d_list)
print(bool_list)
```

Below was the answer to the first version of the question with a simpler 2d list:

```
my_2d_list = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['a','d','c']
]

def bool_func(mylist):
    return [a == b for a, b in zip(*mylist)]

print(bool_func(my_2d_list ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
bool_list = [x == y for x,y in zip(my_2d_list[0], my_2d_list[1])]
```

Comment: How about `zip(*my_2d_list)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might be a bit easier to read:

```
my_2d_list = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['a','d','c']
]

# Only works if inputList is made up of two lists of equal length!
def boolFunc(inputList):
    tempList=[]
    for i in range(len(inputList[0])):
        if inputList[0][i] == inputList[1][i]:
            tempList.append(True)
        else:
            tempList.append(False)
    return tempList

print(boolFunc(my_2d_list))
```

Comment: Instead of the conditional, you can use `tempList.append(inputList[0][i] == inputList[1][i])`